# Javascript regex - matching word in sentence with "+" character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having an issue properly testing this sentence.

> "code in c++ and javascript"

I want to match c++ and javascript, but not java. I solved not matching java by introducing a word boundary test on both sides `\b`.

[image]

Solved with word boundary test.

[image]

Now the issue - The same approach is not working with "c++", although it seems to me it should be. Is there something I am missing?

[image]

And without word boundary

[image]

Comment: `\b` is just something like `^|[^\w]|$`. Try to use `(?:\s|^|$)` instead.

Comment: The reason it is not working is because the + is not considered part of a word.  Just check the way that you have it in the last example.

Comment: Maybe `\b(c\+\+|java\b)`? https://regex101.com/r/iX9jW7/1

Comment: `(?:\s|^)(.*?)(?=\s|$)` will capture all sentence words. [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/eX6yF7/1)

Comment: @vp_arth That will match `java`.

Comment: @chris85, yes, I guess I correct understand the issue :)

Comment: What context do youwant to match `c++` in? Then either use `\bc\+{2}\B`  or just `c\+{2}`. Or even `\bc\+{2}(?![-\w])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `+` is not considered a word character, having a `\b` after `+` won't work.

You can fix your regex by using a negative lookahead instead of `\b` on RHS:

```
/\bc\+\+(?!\w)/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fQ2tY3/2)

To match both `java` and `c++` in alternation:

```
/\b(?:c\+\+|java)(?!\w)/
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to match both with the same regex?  Or independently?  This will match c++ if that's what you need:

```
c\+{2}
```

Answer (score 1):

For c++ you can try below

```
/c\+{2}$/
```